# Mimic struct.field using reflect

Tags: go, struct, reflection

How can I get the same value as `reflect.TypeOf(struct.field)` when using `FieldByName` when the field is an interface type?

As seen [here](https://play.golang.org/p/zVvoWpHYXR6), if a struct field is an interface, `reflect.TypeOf(struct.field)` gives me the concrete type, but `reflect.ValueOf(struct).FieldByName("field").Type()` gives me the interface. Is it possible to get the concrete type stored in `struct.field` using reflect if all I have is `struct` and `"field"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Elem()`

> // Elem returns the value that the interface v contains

Correct way to extract the type

`reflect.ValueOf(h).Elem().FieldByName("i").Elem().Type().String()`